# Android: Launching gallery app, picking multiple images, returning URIs

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

I'm attempting to launch the Gallery app (or any third party gallery apps) from my application in order to allow the user to select multiple images, then return the URIs. I am currently able to select a single image, however I can't figure out how to select more than one.

I don't really want to use a custom gallery. However, if there is no way to solve this problem without using one, I suppose that's the approach I will have to take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if you ever found an answer to this, but since I've been looking for something similar, I figure I would reply.

There doesn't appear to be a way to select multiple images without using or writing a custom version of the gallery.  If you haven't already come across it, there is an open source one available at:

https://github.com/vikaskanani/Android-Custom-Gallery-And-Instant-Upload

and the writer's blog is available

http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/android-custom-gallery-and-instant-upload-project/

It allows for multiple selection, image preview and taking photos.  It seems to be targeted for Android 2.3.1 but I believe without much trouble it will work with Android 2.2.

It seems to work pretty simply and you should be able to modify it for your project as needed.

Comment: Yeah. I figured it wasn't possible after googling some more. Have ended up implementing a custom gallery. Thanks anyway!